# How to create the Connection between the two instance of the same code using Accept and Connect Calls

Tags: c, linux, tcp, ip, distributed-computing

I needs to create the ring of processes and one master process connected with all process in the ring.Ring process will get the information of it's left neighbour from the master process. The ring process has to connect to its left neighbour and also accept connection from the right neighbour to create the ring.

Can you please let me know how to connect and accept the connection for the ring process.

Here is the code, I have tried to make it happen. Accepting first, will make all process waiting for accepting the request and connecting first will, will make all connection refused as no one is accepting the request.

```
//----------------Connect to Left Neighbour.............

left_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (left_sock < 0 ) 
    {
        perror("socket Left:");
        exit(left_sock);
    }

  /* set up the address and port */
    left_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    left_addr.sin_port = htons(left_port);
    memcpy(&left_addr.sin_addr, left_host->h_addr_list[0], left_host->h_length);

  /* connect to socket at above addr and port */
    rc = connect(left_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&left_addr, sizeof(left_addr));
    if ( rc < 0 ) 
    {
        perror("connect Left:");
        exit(rc);
    }

    printf("Connected Left\n");

    //----- Accept from Right------
    right_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (right_sock < 0 ) 
    {
        perror("socket right:");
        exit(right_sock);
    }

  /* set up the address and port */
    right_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    right_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    right_addr.sin_port = htons(right_port);

    if (bind(right_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&right_addr, sizeof(right_addr))<0)
    {
        perror("Right: bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Listener on port %d \n", right_port);

    if (listen(right_sock, 10) < 0)
    {
        perror("Right listen:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int incoming_len = sizeof(incoming);

    int p = accept(right_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&incoming, &incoming_len);

    if ( p < 0 ) 
    {
        perror("Accept:");
        exit(p);
    }
    ihp = gethostbyaddr((char *)&incoming.sin_addr, sizeof(struct in_addr), AF_INET);
    printf("Connected to %s\n", ihp->h_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

A standard technique is:

- make `left_sock` nonblocking; call `connect`; verify that `errno == EINPROGRESS`
- call `listen` on `right_sock`
- call `select` with `left_sock` selected for writing, and `right_sock` selected for reading.

When `select` indicates readability, it is safe to `accept` (it may fail, but will not block). When `select` indicates writability, test `SO_ERROR` for being 0. Keep selecting until both socket states are determined.

Comment: Thanks for the technique. I tried it for 3 ring processes, the first process tries to writes, but not able to do so. The other two process got stuck at the select system call. If I kill the first process then, second will start behaving like first one and so on